# Rococo onchain parachain registration not working

Tags: parachain, rococo

I'm trying to onboard a team to paraID2000 on Rococo, but I'm not being able to do so successfully. The ID was previously being used by another team that attempted to upgrade their chain and bricked it. What I did was to manually delete the `futureCodeHash` for that previous chain, deregister the paraID, and then re-register it with the new team's information (`registar.forceRegister(who, deposit,id,gensis,wasm`)). Still, the parachain is not producing blocks and I'm not entirely sure why.

Did I miss any steps in the middle? How can I best debug this?

Comment: Not an expert on this but I think the parachain id is meant to not use twice. Probably it's just easier to register another parachain if it's just for local testing

Comment: You can request rococo onboarding of a parachain here: https://github.com/paritytech/subport/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Rococo&template=rococo.yaml

Answer (score 1):

It shows what steps should be taken for **offboarding** a parachain or parathread from the system in the Polkadot codebase [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/parachains/src/paras/mod.rs#L1129), which includes the following:

- ◻ Remove the registered parachain id from the head-data storage item `<Self as Store>::Heads::remove(&para)`
- ◻ Remove the registered parachain id from the `FutureCodeUpgrades` storage item `<Self as Store>::FutureCodeUpgrades::remove(&para)`
- ◻ Remove the registered parachain id from the `UpgradeGoAheadSignal` storage item `<Self as Store>::UpgradeGoAheadSignal::remove(&para)`
- ◻ Remove the registered parachain id from the `UpgradeRestrictionSignal` storage item `<Self as Store>::UpgradeRestrictionSignal::remove(&para)`
- ◻ Decrease the number of references of the validation code and remove it from storage if zero is reached, which involves

  - ☑ Copy the `FutureCodeHash` for that parachain id and remove it from `FutureCodeHash` storage

    ```
    let removed_future_code_hash = <Self as Store>::FutureCodeHash::take(&para)
    ```
  - ◻ If that `FutureCodeHash` value is not `None`, then you need to use that copied `FutureCodeHash` as the `ValidationCodeHash` (`code_hash`) in the `decrease_code_ref` function shown [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/parachains/src/paras/mod.rs#L1959)

    ```
    if let Some(removed_future_code_hash) = removed_future_code_hash {
        Self::decrease_code_ref(&removed_future_code_hash);
    }
    ```

    - ◻ In `decrease_code_ref` you provide it as an argument to `CodeByHashRefs`.

      - Obtain its `refs` storage value, as shown below:

        ```
        fn decrease_code_ref(code_hash: &ValidationCodeHash) -> Weight {
            ...
            let refs = <Self as Store>::CodeByHashRefs::get(code_hash)
        ```
      - If `refs == 0` then no further action is required in this step.
      - Else if `refs <= 1` then remove that `code_hash` value from the storage values `CodeByHash` and `CodeByHashRefs` as shown below:

        ```
        <Self as Store>::CodeByHash::remove(code_hash);
        <Self as Store>::CodeByHashRefs::remove(code_hash);
        ```
      - Otherwise you need to insert a value into `CodeByHashRefs` storage, where the key is that `code_hash` and the value is `refs - 1` as shown below:

        ```
        <Self as Store>::CodeByHashRefs::insert(code_hash, refs - 1);
        ```
- ◻ Note the replacement of code for the parachain id, in the context of the current relay-chain block number, and provide the replaced code, which involves:

  - ◻ Copy the `CurrentCodeHash` for that parachain id and remove it from `CurrentCodeHash` storage

    ```
    let removed_code_hash = <Self as Store>::CurrentCodeHash::take(&para)
    ```
  - ◻ If that `CurrentCodeHash` value is not `None`, then you need to do the following in the `note_past_code` function:

    - Use that copied `CurrentCodeHash` as the `ValidationCodeHash` (`old_code_hash`) in the `note_past_code` function shown [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/parachains/src/paras/mod.rs#L1187), as shown below:

      ```
      if let Some(removed_code_hash) = removed_code_hash {
          Self::note_past_code(para, now, now, removed_code_hash);
      }
      ```
    - ◻ In the `note_past_code` function it shows you have to update the `PastCodeMeta` for that parachain id, and the current relay-chain block number, which requires updating the `upgrade_times` property of `ParaPastCodeMeta` by pushing a new `ReplacementTimes { expected_at, activated_at }` value where `expected_at` and `activated_at` are both the current relay-chain block number.

      ```
      <Self as Store>::PastCodeMeta::mutate(&id, |past_meta| {
          past_meta.note_replacement(at, now);
      });

      ...

      impl<N: Ord + Copy + PartialEq> ParaPastCodeMeta<N> {
          // note a replacement has occurred at a given block number.
          pub(crate) fn note_replacement(&mut self, expected_at: N, activated_at: N) {
              self.upgrade_times.push(ReplacementTimes { expected_at, activated_at })
          }

      ...

      /// Metadata used to track previous parachain validation code that we keep in
      /// the state.
      ...
      pub struct ParaPastCodeMeta<N> {
          upgrade_times: Vec<ReplacementTimes<N>>,
      ```
    - ◻ In the `note_past_code` function, it shows you have to insert the `old_code_hash` as the new value of a key that is a tuple containing the parachain id and the current relay-chain block number:

      ```
      <Self as Store>::PastCodeHash::insert(&(id, at), old_code_hash);
      ```
    - ◻ In the `note_past_code` function, it shows you need to update `PastCodePruning` storage by finding the index of the current relay-chain block number, and then inserting a new tuple value under that index `(id, now)`, which is the parachain id and the current relay-chain block number

      ```
      <Self as Store>::PastCodePruning::mutate(|pruning| {
          let insert_idx =
              pruning.binary_search_by_key(&now, |&(_, b)| b).unwrap_or_else(|idx| idx);
          pruning.insert(insert_idx, (id, now));
      });

      ...

      #[pallet::storage]
      pub(super) type PastCodePruning<T: Config> =
          StorageValue<_, Vec<(ParaId, T::BlockNumber)>, ValueQuery>;
      ```

It also shows what steps to take to **deregister** a parachain:

- ☑ Deregister a parachain as shown in the function [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/common/src/paras_registrar.rs#L538)

If you have only manually deleted the `FutureCodeHash` for the previous parachain id and deregistered the parachan, then it seems you have only finished doing the steps where I have checked the checkboxes above, and hopefully you made a copy of the `FutureCodeHash` before deleting it, but it appears you still have to do the other offboarding steps that are indicated above with unchecked checkboxes.